# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory os.unlink

Tags: python

New to code, trying to run a tsp art python script on Mac osx 10.9.5 and I always get this error, does it have to do with the temporary files? Thanks

```
Loading bitmap file easy.pbm ...  done; 28138 stipples
Writing TSP solver input file /var/folders/kd/2c6gv9q97vs716cv7s8n2fsc0000gn/T/easy._jlpel.tsp ...  done
Running TSP solver ... 
Solver failed; status = 127

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/DH/tspart.py", line 263, in <module>
    os.unlink( solfile )
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'easy.tour'
>>>
```

Comment: your script is trying to remove (AKA unlink) a file which does not exist, at least in this directory. Do you modify this script? You should print the current path (`os.getcwd()`) to see where you are. If that's a "normal" fact that the file is missing sometimes, then check for existence first or trap the OSError.

Comment: the script was not modified, the path to an .exe file was not specified, works now.